# How can I let the user download the HTML-file?

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, invoice

I would like to create an Invoice in HTML instead of a PDF-file. And I would like to let the user easyli download the HTML-file via a link. How can I do this?

If I simply link to the HTML file, it is only "temporarily downloaded" and view in the users web browser. I would like the same effect as when the user download a `.zip`-file or similar. I think that I have seen this functionally in webmail systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) like so:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.html"
```

This will tell the browser to save the file instead of parsing it. How to do that depends on what you're using, in PHP you'd use the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Set a content-disposition header (or remind people about the Save As option on their menus)